# Comparing instances of concepts in Semantic Web?

Tags: terminology, semantic-web

I am new to Semantic Web, and don't quite know what is the terminology for having instances of the same concepts or same inherited concepts? Can we call the instances equal if they belong to the same concept or subconcept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two instances of the same concept are in the same class. You can't really say anything more than than that. Suppose you have a concept `Colour`, and two instances `red` and `green`. They (presumably) aren't equal, but they are both members the Colour class, and may jointly be members of other classes as well (e.g. `PrimaryColours`, `TrafficLightColours`).

Note that I say that `red` and `green` *may* not be equal. In the semantic web, we generally make the *open world assumption*, i.e. that we don't assume that we have all of the relevant information yet, and we don't make the *unique name assumption* - so things with different names may denote the same thing. So unless `red` and `green` are explicitly stated to be different ([`owl:differentFrom`](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#differentFrom-def)), it's possible that, under the open world assumption, new information could show up to say, or infer, that they actually denote the same resource ([`owl:sameAs`](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#sameAs-def))

Comment: Is it possible to find out whether two instances are of the same class, programmatically (Using api such as JENA)?

Comment: Yes, there are a variety of ways to do that. StackOverflow is set up to curate a collection of specific questions with their best answers. So it would be best if this follow-up question was asked on its own, then you can see suggestions from the community on that specific topic.

Answer (score 0):

The equals method on a Jena Resource works out whether one resource is the same as another, not the same type as another. To work this out something like this will suffice:

```
if (resource1.hasProperty(model.createProperty("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#", "type"), model.createResource("http://typeUri")) && resource2.hasProperty(model.createProperty("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#", "type"), model.createResource("http://typeUri"))) {
    // both resources are the same type
}
```